# c# Exception thrown in a thread is caught in an other thread

Tags: c#

I read in this post (http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/238006-cannot-catch-exception-thread#post970280) that: 'Thrown exceptions are stack-bound objects. Since every thread has its
own stack, an exception thrown in thread A cannot suddenly appear in
thread B'

But I have a project in which exactly this seems to happen. i am kind of desperate to find the source of my problem. what i am doing is calling 10 threads, of which each one runs several tools simultaneously. each tool is run in yet another thread by starting an executable in a process. this means if i have e.g. 2 tools i will have 10x2 threads in total. the problem is the following: if an exception is thrown, e.g. when one of the tool threads fails and i want to catch it inside the same thread, it happens that any of the threads catches the exception. I verify that by letting the run method output by letting the runTool function include the threadId and toolId in the exception that it throws and comparing the output from the throw and the catch

here the simplified code:

```
class Worker
{

private ManualResetEvent[] threadResetEvents;
private ManualResetEvent[][] toolResetEvents;
private Tool[] tools;
public int stopped = false;


public void run(int threadNo)
{
    threadResetEvents = new ManualResetEvent[threadNo];
    toolResetEvents = new ManualResetEvent[threadNo][];
    for (int i = 0; i < threadNo; i++)
    {
        threadResetEvents[i] = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(fillDb), (object)i);
    }
    sendToObservers("Filling database...");
    WaitHandle.WaitAll(threadResetEvents);
}

private void fillDb(object obj)
    {
    int threadId = (int)obj;
    while (!stopped)
            {
        toolResetEvents[threadId] = new ManualResetEvent[tools.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < tools.Length; i++)
        {
            toolResetEvents[threadId][i] = new ManualResetEvent(false);
            ToolInfoObject info = new ToolInfoObject(threadId, i);
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(runTool), info);
        }
        WaitHandle.WaitAll(toolResetEvents[threadId]);
    }
}

private void runTool(object obj)
{
    ToolInfoObject info = (ToolInfoObject) i;
    int threadId = info.threadId;
    int toolId = info.toolId;
    try
    {
        tools[toolId].runTool(threadId, toolId);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Exception caught in Thread " + threadId + ", Tool " + toolId + ": " + e.GetBaseException());
    }
}

}

class ToolInfoObject
{
public int threadId;
public int toolId;

public ToolInfoObject(int thread, int tool)
{
    this.threadId = thread;
    this.toolId = tool;
}
}
```

I'd be grateful for any help

***EDIT:***

in more detail, the problem shows up when an IOException is thrown. i let every tool create a directory and files in it based on the thread number. if a file is not accessible it will lead to a message like this:

> Exception caught in Thread 1, Tool 0: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Die Datei "C:\tmpdir\3\log.txt" konnte nicht gefunden werden.

which means the exception actuall happened in thread 3, but was caught in thread 1

Comment: What version of the framework are you using. 4.0 makes some of this stuff eaiser

Comment: Where is `i` coming from (`ToolInfoObject info = (ToolInfoObject) i`?
When using ThreadPools the threads will be reused - you will see the same Thread Id for different operations. Might that be your problem?

Comment: This code contains multiple errors. So it is not real. I suspect your problem isn't real either.  Try making a small complete sample and post that.

Comment: i am using 4.0 already - the ToolInfoObject contains the parameters for the runtool function - int stopped should be bool stopped - the code is real, although this is just the simplified version (with some errors, i have to admit)

Comment: Still leaves a lot of open points. Do you catch (and re-throw) the exceptions at any point? Any static classes involved?

Comment: there are no static classes involved. i do catch and rethrow the execption in the Tool class. could that be the problem?

Answer (score 3):

Check if your `Tool` is threadsafe. If it is not this can lead to your problem.

Comment: the Tool class does not communicate with other threads at all, does that mean it is thread safe?

Comment: no, to make it short it's thread-safe if it uses only local objects and access other thread-safe methods.

Comment: the Tool class uses only local objects, but reads a textfile, accesses a mysql database and runs an executable in a process. could some of that cause the problem?

Comment: In order to be thread-safe and reentrant you must not access any field of the class that is not readonly and only use thread-safe methods of other classes. E.g. you are not allowed to store the filename, filestream or threadId in any field value of the tool class but use local variables in the method instead.

Comment: No, I only see `tools[toolId]` which should be safe.

Comment: @Henk Holterman Yes exactly, and this means it is reused for all the threads spawned in the first loop. It would need to be tool[threadId, toolId]

Comment: that is true. i'll try to create a Tool instance for each Thread like 'Tool tool = tools[toolId]; tool.runTool(threadId, toolId);

Comment: @F.G. Creating a new reference to the same tool instance does not change anything. It's still the same instance. Either you have to create a new instance using new Tool() or you must make the tool implementation thread-safe.

Comment: creating an own instance for each thread did the trick, did not know that. thank you